# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'

Tags: python, api, module, python-module

I am working with Atom in a trade-bot with Alpacas, and tried to intstall the Alpacas library with `$ pip3 install alpaca-trade-api`, as shown in the Github page (https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python), but when i try to run it with `import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi` , the terminal shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'`  .

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-af2e0ff0b3ba> in <module>
----> 1 import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpaca_trade_api'
```

Comment: Are you currently using a virtual environment? Also, have you checked to make sure the module installed with pip using `pip list`? Also, your example shows you trying to import your module with underscores when your pip command uses dashes. Have you tried it with dashes?

Comment: If you are using an environment install to that environment and if you are in a linux machine maybe arch try to use it with `sudo` because it may install it for both user and root.

Comment: @ptan9o I am using atom with Script and Hydrogen, it hasn't caused other problems yet. By using `pip list`, it shows the alpaca module installed. The example shown in Github shows it with underscores, and when y try with dashes it tells me that is a syntax error.

Comment: @ByteWaiser It worked with Spyder, but why can't I run it on Atom? Also, II'm on Windows

Comment: you may have two Python installed (ie. Python 2 and Python 3) and `pip3` can install for one Python (Python 3) but `Atom` may use other Python to run it. Check in console/terminal `python3 your_script.py`. BTW: `Spyder` can also use first Python to run it.

Comment: BTW: in code use `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` and `print( sys.executable )` to see which Python is used to run it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with

pip install alpaca_trade_api

instead of

pip3 install alpaca_trade_api   (mentioned in medium tutorial)

I'm using anaconda

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue while trying ALpaca API read.

"pip install alpaca_trade_api" solved the issue for me.